# Beyond Bounds Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app has a table view with a list of jobs it gets from a Parse table. The user can hit the "+" button on the navigation bar to go to another screen to create a new job. Once the new job is created, it returns to the list of jobs with the one that was just created now being added to the list. The problem is that I can select the two jobs that were already in the list with no problems but when I try to select the new job, the app crashes with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
```

Here is the code for the jobs list:

```
#import "UnassignedJobs.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NavController.h"
#import "LogInViewController.h"
#import "NewJobViewController.h"
#import "JobDetailViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface UnassignedJobs ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jobs;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectIds;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refresh;

@end

@implementation UnassignedJobs

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];

    UIBarButtonItem *logoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(logoutPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton;

    UIBarButtonItem *newJobButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(createJob)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newJobButton;

    NSString *currentUserFullName = [[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"Name"];
    if ([currentUserFullName isEqualToString:@"Cory Pollard"] || [currentUserFullName isEqualToString:@"Richie Ray"]) {
        newJobButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        newJobButton.enabled = NO;
    }

    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);

    self.loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, 37, 37)];
    self.loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2 - 37);
    self.loadingIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
    self.loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    self.loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingIndicator];
    [self.loadingIndicator startAnimating];

    [self getJobs];

    self.refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    self.refresh.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = self.refresh;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)getJobs {
    self.jobs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.objectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Jobs"];
    [query setLimit:1000];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            for (NSDictionary *objectDictionary in objects) {
                NSString *assigned = [objectDictionary objectForKey:@"assigned"];
                if ([assigned isEqualToString:@"no"]) {
                    [self.jobs addObject:objectDictionary];
                    // self.objectIds = [objects valueForKeyPath:@"objectId"];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < self.jobs.count; i++) {
                    [self.objectIds addObject:[self.jobs valueForKeyPath:@"objectId"]];
                }
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

                [self.tableView reloadData];

                [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
            });
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)createJob {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NewJobViewController *jobCreateScreen = [[NewJobViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewJobViewController" bundle:nil];
    NavController *newJobNav = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:jobCreateScreen];
    newJobNav.delegate = jobCreateScreen;

    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = newJobNav;
}

- (void)logoutPressed {
    [PFUser logOut];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    LogInViewController *loginScreen = [[LogInViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LogInViewController" bundle:nil];
    NavController *loginNavController = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginScreen];
    loginNavController.delegate = loginScreen;

    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = loginNavController;
}

- (void)refreshData {
    [self getJobs];

    [self.refresh endRefreshing];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.jobs.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    NSDictionary *jobDictionary = [self.jobs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    if (cell) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        cell.textLabel.text = [jobDictionary objectForKey:@"job"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *jobDictionary = [self.jobs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    JobDetailViewController *jobDetails = [[JobDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"JobDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    jobDetails.jobName = [jobDictionary objectForKey:@"job"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    // [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    jobDetails.jobDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[jobDictionary objectForKey:@"date"]];

    jobDetails.objectId = [[self.objectIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    jobDetails.assignedWorker = [jobDictionary objectForKey:@"worker"];
    jobDetails.details = [jobDictionary objectForKey:@"details"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:jobDetails animated:YES];
}

@end
```

And here is the code to create a new job:

```
#import "NewJobViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NavController.h"
#import "TabController.h"
#import "UnassignedJobs.h"
#import "AssignedJobs.h"
#import "MyJobs.h"
#import "Users.h"
#import "CompletedJobs.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface NewJobViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *jobName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *detailTextView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *createJobButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *jobDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dateString;

@end

@implementation NewJobViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"Create Job";

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;

    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateString) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)returnToMainScreen {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    UnassignedJobs *unassignedJobs = [[UnassignedJobs alloc]initWithNibName:@"UnassignedJobs" bundle:nil];
    unassignedJobs.title = @"Unassigned";
    NavController *navController = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:unassignedJobs];
    navController.delegate = unassignedJobs;

    AssignedJobs *assignedJobs = [[AssignedJobs alloc]initWithNibName:@"AssignedJobs" bundle:nil];
    assignedJobs.title = @"Assigned";
    NavController *assignedNav = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:assignedJobs];
    assignedNav.delegate = assignedJobs;

    CompletedJobs *completed = [[CompletedJobs alloc]initWithNibName:@"CompletedJobs" bundle:nil];
    completed.title = @"Completed";
    NavController *completedNav = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:completed];
    completedNav.delegate = completed;

    MyJobs *myJobs = [[MyJobs alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyJobs" bundle:nil];
    myJobs.title = @"My Jobs";
    NavController *myNav = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myJobs];
    myNav.delegate = myJobs;

    Users *userList = [[Users alloc]initWithNibName:@"Users" bundle:nil];
    userList.title = @"Users";
    NavController *userNav = [[NavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:userList];
    userNav.delegate = userList;

    TabController *tabController = [[TabController alloc]init];
    tabController.viewControllers = @[navController, assignedNav, completedNav, myNav, userNav];

    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabController;
}

- (void)updateDateString {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    self.dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    self.jobDate = [formatter dateFromString:self.dateString];
}

- (IBAction)createJob:(id)sender {
    PFObject *job = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Jobs"];
    job[@"job"] = self.jobName.text;
    job[@"details"] = self.detailTextView.text;
    job[@"assigned"] = @"no";
    job[@"date"] = self.jobDate;
    [job saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            // Close this window and return to unassigned jobs
            [self returnToMainScreen];
        }
        else {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Job could not be saved!" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlert show];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)cancel {
    [self returnToMainScreen];
}

# pragma mark UITextView Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

# pragma mark UITextField Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: That is a lot of code! Could you narrow it down a little to what you think is related to the problem?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the array that populates the table view but it is returning the correct number of rows so I'm not sure why I can't select that new row.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reload the jobs data source, and show the table again,

so,

```
@implementation UnassignedJobs ...
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self getJobs];
[self.table reloadData];
}
```

and dont forget to clean the mutable arrays

```
- (void)getJobs {
    [self.jobs removeAllObjects];
    [self.objectIds removeAllObjects];
    self.jobs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.objectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

MaKo is correct in stating you need to reload the jobs data source (because after you pop back to the table controller, the data source won't know about the new row until it is reloaded. However, you don't need to re-initiate the arrays (even if you did this, you wouldn't need to remove all the objects first since it's redundant). It would be better practice to maintain your existing arrays properly than to create new ones each time.

Comment: It is returning the correct number of rows with the correct data in each row. The problem is when I select the new row.

Comment: Could you include your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: It is included in my post.

Comment: I've deleted all data from my Parse table and created three new entries from the app. They all get added and I can select the first two rows in the jobs list but it still crashes when selecting the third row.

Comment: My bad. Try logging `self.jobs` right before this line `NSDictionary *jobDictionary = [self.jobs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` I'm guessing there will be two objects in that array. If so, then there is an issue with the maintenance of objects in the `self.jobs` array.

Comment: It actually appears to be an issue with my objectIds array. The jobs array has the correct number of objects but objectIds has double the amount (6)

Comment: I removed the line in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: that uses the objectIds array and it all worked fine. I need that array though.

Comment: Was just in the middle of typing when you commented again... that makes sense too. You can probably avoid this crash by setting jobDetails.objectId more efficiently, but unless you need/want the items you've deleted, it's probably being managed incorrectly. Take a look at your code again. You add objects to the self.objectIds array, but do not remove them when items are deleted from the table.

Comment: Fixed it. I moved the for loop that adds objects to the objectIds array outside of the loop it was in.